# Make all object properties accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to search about this but i didn't found the answer yet. i want to spread all object properties so can be accessed right away

```
import * as formulajs from '@formulajs/formulajs' // import entire package

formulasjs.SUM() // this working but i dont want the SUM inside formulasjs

//how to spread like this
const {...formulasjs} = formulasjs // i know this is wrong
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@formulajs/formulajs

How can i make all properties accessible? like SUM(), IF(), ROUND()

i can't do import { SUM } from '@formulajs/formulajs', because i want get the formula from back-end in string & using eval() to run it

i know i can import { SUM, IF, ROUND, etc } from '@formulajs/formulajs' but it's too many, maybe there's another simple way?

Comment: You can't. Instead, you may rename `formulasjs` to something shorter like `f`, or list all the function names in the destructuring that you want to access.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with - it's deprecated, and not available at all in strict mode.

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as formulajs from '@formulajs/formulajs';
const formulaString = 'SUM';
if (formulajs.hasOwnProperty(formulaString) && typeof formulajs[formulaString] === 'function') {
  const result = eval(`formulajs.${formulaString}(/* arguments */)`);
  console.log(result);
} else {
  console.error(`Formula "${formulaString}" not found.`);
}
```

*The formula is dynamically selected based on the string received from the backend, and eval() is used to execute it.*

Comment: How is that an improvement over the thing they literally said they didn't want to do?

Comment: I have updated the code, may be it will helpful for you.